# How can I get first attribute from XML?

Tags: xml

How can I get first question after serialization my xml file (without `foreach`)?
I want get `QuestionText="2*2"` in label, and variant in my radio button.

```
 public class Question
    {
        [XmlAttribute ("QuestionText") ] public string qstn;
        [XmlArrayItem("Variant")] public string[] Variants;
        [XmlArrayItem("Answer")] public string[] Answers;
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public List<Question> Questions = new List<Question>();

        public void SerializeToXML(string Path)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(Path);
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, this);
            textWriter.Close();
        }

        public static Test DeserializeFromXML(string Path)
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Test));
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(Path);
            Test test;
            test = (Test) deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            textReader.Close();
            return test;
        }
```

**My XML:**

```
<Question QuestionText="2*2">
  <Variants>
    <Variant>1</Variant>
    <Variant>4</Variant>
    <Variant>5</Variant>
  </Variants>
  <Answers>
    <Answer>4</Answer>
  </Answers>
</Question>
<Question QuestionText="3*2">
  <Variants>
    <Variant>1</Variant>
    <Variant>4</Variant>
    <Variant>5</Variant>
  </Variants>
  <Answers>
    <Answer>4</Answer>
    <Answer>number</Answer>
  </Answers>
</Question>
<Question QuestionText="4*2">
  <Variants>
    <Variant>1</Variant>
    <Variant>8</Variant>
  </Variants>
  <Answers>
    <Answer>4</Answer>
    <Answer>somenumber</Answer>
    <Answer>anynumber</Answer>
  </Answers>
</Question>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

//Using factory get an instance of document builder

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

//parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file

dom = db.parse("your xml");

Element documentElement = dom.getDocumentElement();

//get a nodelist of the Employee elements
  **NodeList employeeNodeList = documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Question ");**

//For first element
 **employeeNodeList.item(0) ;**

Comment: This c#? what is dom? which reference DocumentBuilderFactory?